# Bash problem with function that hides files

Tags: bash, shell, mv

I have this function

```
function hide {
    for f in "$@"; do
        if [[ ! ${f::1} == '.' ]]; then
            mv $f .$f
        fi
    done
}
```

that should hide a file passed as input, if it is not already hidden.

When I use it on files whose names contain spaces, like:

```
touch "ciao ciao"
hide ciao\ ciao
```

it doesn't work and I get this error instead:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

I tried changing `.$f` to `."$f"` in the mv command but I still get the error.

Comment: Quote your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Jetchisel, you need to quote the variables when passing args to `mv` to ensure spaces are preserved:

```sh
function hide {
    for f in "$@"; do
        if [[ ! ${f::1} == '.' ]]; then
            mv "$f" ".$f"  # <= note variable references are quoted
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: I was leaving the . outside of the quotes

Comment: That should work okay, as long as both `$f` become `"$f"`.  For example, try the following: `f="a b"; printf "<<%s>>\n" .$f ".$f" ."$f"`

Answer (score 3):

Improving @rtx13 's answer:

- Handle full paths safely
- Prioritize use of POSIX syntax over Bash specifics.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

hide ()
{
  # Without in, for loop iterates arguments
  for path; do

    # Strips-out the leading directory path to keep file name only
    file="${path##*/}"

    # If file name starts with a dot, continue to next argument
    [ -n "${file##.*}" ] || continue

    # Strips out the trailing file name to keep the leading directory path only
    base="${path%/*}"

    # If base is same as file, then there is no leading dir, so prepend current
    if [ "$base" = "$file" ]; then
      base='.'
      path="./$path"
    fi

    # Performs the file rename
    mv --no-clobber -- "$path" "$base/.$file" # Always double quote variables expansion
  done
}
```

**EDIT**:

Following [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf)'s good comments.

1. Simplified but kept the harmless `--` options terminator as a lead to good practice.
2. Added `--no-clobber` to not overwrite existing files.

Comment: Heh. In trying to validate one of the finer points of syntax here, I learned that something I'd been taught isn't correct for the current version of the POSIX specification; specifically, I'd been instructed to leave out the `;` when not using an `in` for strict compliance (thus, just `for path do`) -- but at least as of issue 7, the standard explicitly permits either form.

Comment: Why are you testing whether the file is writable?

Comment: Using `--` (while a good habit) doesn't look necessary since everything is prepend with `./` anyway.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf not needed indeed. I'd need to test the permission to write in the leading directory. About `--`, it does not cause harm and a good practice. It was added before I fixed the script to prepend the directory path.

Comment: Missed that it was for the dir. Makes sense.